# Add element <button> on ng2-pdf-viewer Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, pdf

I need to display `PDF file` on my component using `ng2-pdf-viewer`, but one of its requirement,I need to add `button download`and it must overlapping `PDF file`, try to find any reference regarding this but none found, this is what I had tried,

**component.html**

```
        <button (click)="toggle()">VIEW RECEIPT</button>
        <div style="height:715px">
            <pdf-viewer *ngIf="isHideReceipt" [autoresize]="true" [src]="pdfSrc" [original-size]="false"
                [render-text]='false' [show-all]="false" style="display: block;position: relative"
                [fit-to-page]="true">
            </pdf-viewer>
            <button (click)="download()">Download PDF</button>
        </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
  pdfSrc = '../../assets/pdf/bla3.pdf';

  toggle() {
    this.isHideReceipt = !this.isHideReceipt;
  }

  download() {
    const blob = this.pdfSrc;
    saveAs(blob, 'test1.pdf');
  }
```

**as per-requirement** (button download overlapping pdf), Im trying using CSS like `z-index` but none work, it is possible ?

link to [official ng2-pdf-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer)
[image: button download overlapping pdf]

Comment: What do you mean by ```it doesn't work```? Is it not showing up, is it showing up in the wrong place? And please post the rest of your css code if you have any.

Comment: the button download doesnt showed up, its not overlapping `pdf file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the button element to have an absolute position and it's parent container to have a relative position. That way you'll be able to overlap onto the pdf viewer:

```
        <button (click)="toggle()">VIEW RECEIPT</button>
        <div style="position: relative; height:715px;">
            <pdf-viewer *ngIf="isHideReceipt" [autoresize]="true" [src]="pdfSrc" [original-size]="false"
                [render-text]='false' [show-all]="false" style="display: block;position: relative"
                [fit-to-page]="true">
            </pdf-viewer>
            <button style="position: absolute; right: 10px; bottom: 10px;" (click)="download()">Download PDF</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi mate, its work, I just need to learn more about css, position absolute and relative, if it is okay, can you explain more the answer,

Comment: Setting ```position: relative``` to the parent means it's positioned relative to itself and not setting bottom/top or left/right properties means it's not going change it's position at all (kind of confusing I know) but the whole purpose of setting it to be relative is so you can set the button's position to be absolute and so it will be relative to the parent container (if the parent container didn't have the relative positioning then the button will really be absolute in it's position and most likely will be at the bottom of the document if the css properties are default)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/ explains it a lot better than I ever could explain ;)